# convert array.push.(prompt()) into a number

Tags: javascript, web

when i run the program the browser tell me moy is NaN yet I took care to use .map(Number) to convert the array into a number . I need some help please.

```js
var score = [];
var i = 0;
var choice = 0;
while(choice != null){
i++;
score.push(prompt("put the score number "+i));
score = score.map(Number);
choice = prompt("to continue click on ok to cancel click on cancel");
}
var sum = 0,moy;
for(a=0;a<=i;a++) {
sum = sum+score[a];
moy = sum/i;
}
document.write("you put  "+i+" score(s) <br>and the average is"+moy);
```

Comment: you need to use `a < i` in your for loop and not `a <= i`

Comment: thank you for your help it work.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in this line

```
for(a=0;a<=i;a++) {
```

define a variable like this

```
for(var  a=0;a<=i;a++)
```